# XDebug never recognise the stops put in php file in vscode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug my php code for the drop downs. I have already gone through other posts on Stackoverflow but still not able to solve the issue.

I have extension installed for php debug, changed the settings in php.ini, launch.json. What else should I do?

launch.json file

```
{      
   "version": "2.6.0",
    "configurations": [
      {         "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 3000,

        },

        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 3000
        }
    ]
}
```

php.ini

```
[XDEBUG]
zend_extension="C:\PHP 7.0v\v7.0\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.show_local_vars = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
;xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1 before
xdebug.remote_host = 10.176.17.108
xdebug.remote_port = 3000
xdebug.remote_mode = req
[MYSQL]
```

Results for php -v:-

```
C:\Users\T0209964\Downloads\MDB-Free_4.8.1>php -v
PHP 7.0.30 (cli) (built: Apr 24 2018 16:30:41) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine. Try to enable logging in launch.json by adding `"log": true` and in xdebug config by adding `xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log`. Probably you will be able to see whats wrong.

I'm not sure that can be an issue but I'm also use option `xdebug.idekey=VSCODE` for configuration xdebug with vscode.

Also make sure you're using that `php.ini` which you're expected (eg. by running `<?php phpinfo();`)

Comment: Thank you DaszuOne!! I had already resolved the error. It was something else. Can you please tell me how to debug javascript in PHP file?

Comment: I'm glad you made it :) As far as I know you can debug javascript straight into your browser using developer tools.